# Push notifications for android

Tags: android, push-notification, phonegap-build

I am developing mobile application using phonegap build and need to implement push notifications (application user receives messages from server). I tried to use example from github plugin PushNotification https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/tree/master/Example/www Anything I do I receive result success: OK, as I could figure out I means only connection is ok. What have I done for that - created project in google developers console, turned google cloud messaging for android on. I haven't changed in example of plugin usage anything, just changed senderID to my Project Number (just compared files). May be the problem is that I run application using phone emulator? Everything else works ok: I open browser, download, install application, also all the other functions work propperly. May be the problem is that I haven't signed for google free trial? (just as I am developing a project for customer, I don't want to enter my card information)

I compile application using phonegap build web interface, my config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "3.6.3" >

    <name>PhoneGap Example</name>

    <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" version="0.7.5" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.1.1" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.3" />

    <description>
        An example application. 
    </description>

    <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="bobo@bopwtein.com">
        Bobo Gopwtein
    </author>

</widget>
```

May be I need to do anything else? Or may be anyone can suggest any tutorial, where it is written completely step by step how to do this?

May be my mistake is that I try to make this using just jquery.mobile and pbonegap build web interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use helper libraries to get push notifications to work in Android emulator. It is said right there in the top of the PushPlugin documentation:

> **important** - Push notifications are intended for real devices. They are not tested for WP8 Emulator. The registration process will fail on
>   the iOS simulator. Notifications can be made to work on the Android
>   Emulator, however doing so requires installation of some helper
>   libraries, as outlined [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/), under the section titled "Installing
>   helper libraries and setting up the Emulator".

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin